# React How to get dynamically generated object name

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, object, react-native

HI i have a problem in accessing the data in the object, my object is

```
profile: Object {
  "-L6LmpGWAClPdVK-cqvh": Object {
    "first_name": "Mithun",
    "isActive": true,
    "isPrimary": true,
    "last_name": "N",
    "phoneNumber": "123454649",
    "title": "Manager",
    "uid": "Vz0pWQV3UxeCbGCbaf7ld4kaNRE3",
  },
  "active": true,
  "businessCategory": "Retail",
  "companyName": "Test"
}
```

Now my question is :

How to access **-L6LmpGWAClPdVK-cqvh** values, this **-L6LmpGWAClPdVK-cqvh** is dynamically generated randomly key.

i can get the value of **this.props.profile.email**

similarly how to get the **this.props.profile.-L6LmpGWAClPdVK-cqvh.first_name** (Currently it says undefined)

Please help!!!

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript there are two ways to access properties in objects. Dot notation object.property and square bracket notation object['property']. Both of these work if you know the name of the property. If you have a variable that stores the name of the property or your property contains characters that are invalid for properties then you can only use the square notation.

```
var key = '-L6LmpGWAClPdVK-cqvh';
var value = object[key];
```

So in your case you would have to use `this.props.profile['-L6LmpGWAClPdVK-cqvh'].first_name`. The `-` in your random name cannot be used as a raw key, has to be a string.

The JS parser will think you are doing `this.props.profile. - L6LmpGWAClPdVK - cqvh.first_name`. Spaces are added for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The key in this case contains the character "-" which is preventing you from accessing through object.(dot) so instead you have to use object['string']

Answer (score 0):

```
We can able to iterate the object. Keys must be strings, and values must be a valid JSON data type (string, number, object, array, boolean or null). On iterating the object will return the keys that the object has. You can access the object values by using dot (.) notation and also by using bracket ([]) notation

for (var data in profile) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(propName)) { //eg: propName which is first_name
        var propValue = data[propName];
        // do something with each element here
    }
}
```